# ConcurrentModificationException when reinserting a node JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I am having a problem with this piece of code:

```
for(Node n : start.getChildren()) {
                    singlewidth = ((CustomController) n).getWidth();
                    totalwidth += singlewidth;
                if(swidth < totalwidth) {
                    //start.getChildren().remove(b);
                    start.getChildren().add(mb);
                    start.getChildren().remove(n);
                }
                if(swidth > totalwidth){
                    start.getChildren().add(n);
                    start.getChildren().remove(mb);
                }
            }
```

The trick here is that I want to go through all the elements in the HBox, and try to adapt them by width. But on the line, where I re-add the Node n, NetBeans throws the ConcurrentModificationException. Can somebody help me please?

Comment: What I do sometimes is create a `List` and add the `Nodes` that will be removed. Then after the loop ends you can remove all the nodes in the list. The other option is to iterate the list.

Comment: Can you please explain how can I use the list iterator in this scenario?

Comment: There are several examples in the link provided.

Comment: BTW: If `start.getChildren().add(n);` is executed, javafx throws an exception since `n` is already a child of `start`. Executing `start.getChildren().add(mb);` more than once results in a exception for the same reason...

Comment: Okay, thank you for the clarification of the problem. I think I'll be able to sort it now.